# Read binary data from a POST request in Python truncated

Tags: java, python, post, binary

I'm sending binary data from java using POST. Here is java code:

```
URL url = new URL(saveURI);
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
urlConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);

urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(length));
OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
out.write(data);
out.flush();
out.close();
```

The size is 150216 bytes. The python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import sys

print "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8"
print

data = sys.stdin.read()
print len(data)

profile= profile_pb2.ProtoCharacter()
profile.ParseFromString(data)
if profile.IsInitialized():
    ProfileWork.saveProfile(profile)
    print profile.tag
```

Gives me 22. What could be the problem here?

**EDIT:** Added more code

Comment: Could you post some more code on how you are retreiving the data in Python, and also what kind of data you are sending from Java?

Comment: Its not from javascript, its from java. The data I transfer is in Google Protocol Buffers format